# How to layout elements with different height nicely?

Tags: css, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

Currently elements(divs) are placed as on the left side of an image.
Is there a way for them to be ordered without spare space between them (as in right side of an image)?

Here's my ui-sortable settings:

```
vm.sortableOptions = {
            'ui-floating': 'auto',
            connectWith: '.connected-columns',
            placeholder: 'board-issue-placeholder'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you put together a representative JS Fiddle?

Comment: Or a Stack Snippet. Definitely needs some more code to be able to reproduce the problem.